Finding the number of zeros on a half plane of $z^4+3z^2 + z + 1$
I found this problem in Berkeley problems in Mathematics:

How many roots has the polynomial $z^4+3z^2 + z + 1$ in the right half $z$-plane?

To this point, I have tried using the method prescribed by this answer in which we can compute what parts of the contour contribute to the winding number, but it seems we get less lucky here that the "real part of $p(it)$ along the contour $[-iR, iR]$ has 4 zeros instead of being all positive. I see how this could contribute two to the winding number, but that isn't definitive since we have $$
\Re(f(it)) = \mathcal{O}(z^4) \quad \text{and} \quad \Im(f(it)) = \mathcal{O}(z).
$$
When you think about it, the contour along $Re^{it}, t \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ contributes a winding number of 2, so one should rule out the possibility of the imaginary line contributing anything.
In general, I'm looking for more strategies to Rouche Theorem problems, and any suggestions would help, thanks!

There are no zeros on the imaginary axis, because the imaginary part of
$$
f(iy)=y^4-3y^2+1+iy
$$
is only  zero for a real $\ y\ $ when $\ y=0\ ,$  and then its real part isn't zero.

@lonzaleggiera I see, so the observation is that in general "contributing to the winding number" corresponds to zeros of both the real and imaginary components, so since there's 4 on the real but none on the imaginary, there's no chance that the image of this segment winds around zero. Did I get that right?

If you're interested in using Rouche's Theorem, maybe consider the function $f\circ g$ where $g:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H}$ denotes the conformal mapping from the unit circle to the right-half complex plane. From there, it becomes a matter of finding a function which'll be smaller (with satisfactory conditions) which is easier to check as having no zeros. (Edit: So exactly like "@\i can try" did.)

Here is a simple solution that does not use Rouché's theorem. $f(z) = z^4 + 3 z^2+ z + 1$ has real coefficients, so its zeros are either real or come in pairs of complex conjugates. But $f$ has no zeros on the real or imaginary axis: For $x \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 f(x) = x^4 + 3 \left( (x + \frac 16)^2 + \frac{11}{36}\right) > 0
$$
and for $y \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 f(iy) = (y^4 - 3 y^2 + 1) + iy \ne 0 \, .
$$
So the roots of $f$ come in two pairs of complex conjugates $z_1, z_2 = \overline{z_1}, z_3, z_4 = \overline{z_3}$. And from Vieta's formulas we get
$$
 0 = z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4  = 2 \bigl(\operatorname{Re}(z_1) + \operatorname{Re}(z_3) \bigr) \, .
$$
It follows that two of the zeros have positive real part, and the other two have negative real part.
More precisely, there is exactly one root in each open quadrant.

Why not take a rotation of Cayley's transform?
Get $$\frac {i-z}{i+z},$$ which takes the unit disk to the right half plane. Call it $\varphi. $
Then $p\circ \varphi $ has as many zeros in the disk as $p(z)$ does on the right half plane (there's none on the boundary).
Use Rouche's,  if possible.

Just to clarify, when looking for roots on the disk, we're using a different variable, say $w = i-z/i+z$, by which we can "carry back" roots to the region?
I feel weird about this only because, doesn't this guarantee that for any conformally equivalent region to the disk, we'd get the same number of zeros?

Sure, but why not?  And you're right,  I sort of forgot to compose.

well to think of an easy example, z(z-1) doesn’t have the same number of roots in the disk as it does the set $\Re z < -1$ even though these are conformally equivalent regions. I think we do have to look at the composition which makes it really hard to do Rouche on the disk (unless it’s much easier than I’m thinking.

Yeah you have to do the composition.   Sometimes Rouche's works.
